# redirect after sign up

Tags: php

I have made a script but after sign up i have an error, it does not redirect me to my index page

here is the code  from insertuser.php

```
include("/pages/classes.php");
$user = new user();
if( isset($_POST['UserName']) && isset($_POST['UserMail']) && isset($_POST['UserPassword'])){
$user->setUserName($_POST['UserName']);
$user->setUserMail($_POST['UserMail']);
$user->setUserPassword(sha1($_POST['UserPassword']));
$user->InsertUser();
header("Location: ../index.php?success=1");
}
```

here is the public function

```
public function InsertUser(){
    include "conn.php";

    $req=$bdd->prepare("Insert into users(UserName,UserMail,UserPassword) Values (:UserName,:UserMail,:UserPassword)");
    $req->execute(array(
    'UserName'=>$this->getUserName(),
    'UserMail'=>$this->getUserMail(),
    'UserPassword'=>$this->getUserPassword()
        ));
}
```

and the link for sign up is

http://demo.legacy-cms.xyz/work/ but dosent return me success=1

Comment: why you don't do it in InsertUser function?

Comment: put header file in inser user function ...

Comment: yes i put it in ijndex.php

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function InsertUser(){
        include "conn.php";
    extrect($_POST);
        $req=$bdd->prepare("Insert into users(UserName,UserMail,UserPassword) Values (:UserName,:UserMail,:UserPassword)");
        $req->execute(array(
        'UserName'=>$this->getUserName(),
        'UserMail'=>$this->getUserMail(),
        'UserPassword'=>$this->getUserPassword()
          ));

    }
.
```

Comment: Noting happen....here is the source files as txt....maybe i forgot something http://demo.legacy-cms.xyz/work/files/

Comment: user added in database after submit?

Comment: did u specify extract($_POST); in insertUser.php

Comment: in rar is the files i have

Comment: sorru  i think i m weak with oops in database .. i m in learning phase with oops

Comment: i extracted the post in insertuser.php but nothing

Comment: why dont u take simple uid as primary key and give it auto increment!

Comment: just take uid in database as in your table and put uid in your query and give it  value NULL. you hve to add uid  through PHPmyadmin

Comment: take a look to the table users,look up

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `UserId` int(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `UserName` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `UserMail` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `UserPassword` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`UserId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```